# Delphi IDE Line Length

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi 7 IDE, do the lines need to be a given length? I see a gray line in some Delphi code I'm working with, and it looks like ever line ends right before it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a guide to line length. Some people don't like long lines because they can be hard to read on different resolutions or when doing comparisons.

Answer (score 17):

It's called the *right margin*. It is intended as a guide to help you avoid writing lines that are too long and exceed your coding standards.  You can switch it off from the Editor Options, as I have done here:

[image]

Comment: No bonus points for anti-aliasing, but nice drawing nevertheless. +1

Answer (score 2):

That gray line is called the margin.

You can set its visibility and position in the *Editor Properties* at the *Display* tab in the *Margin and gutter* groupbox.

The margin is a visual assistent. The standard position is 80 characters, which defaults to the maximum unscrolled size of many source formatting output media, such as the one used here at Stack Overflow. Originally, it had something to do with the paper width on (matrix) printers. Maybe it still does.

Comment: 80 characters was the number of columns on the punched card patented 1928 by IBM. A legacy of the 80 column punched card format is that most character-based terminals display 80 characters per row. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card). Maybe there are still Delphi developers who "punch" their source code as a physical backup ;)